# PHP variable not working in MySQLi statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
$indtag = '';
foreach($pretag as &$indtag) { //cycles through tags, puts quotes into check by tag
    $quote = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT `id`, `$indtag` FROM `beyonce` WHERE `$indtag` LIKE '%$indtag%'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($quote)) {
            echo $row['$indtag'];
            echo $row['id'];
        }
}
```

The table has fields for `id`s, `quote`s, then an individual column for each tag (`ang` for anger being an example). `pretag` is an array full of tags (`rom` is romance, `ang` is anger, `dece` is deception) that I'm running through, trying to find quotes with those IDs and tags. The statement works fine in SQL when I run it with `ang`, it selects the IDs fine, but when I try to select the column/field for a tag using a variable, nothing comes back. Any ideas?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Additionally, try to a void using dynamic column names unless you've very carefully screened them against a known-good list.

Comment: Any particular reason why `foreach($pretag as &$indtag)` by reference?

Comment: I'm actually fairly alarmed that you have a table named beyonce...

Comment: I'm not sure this is your whole problem, but I don't think this line would work.

`echo $row['$indtag'];`

I think that need to be double qouted.

Comment: @BrokenBinary:  Damn, just read right over that. Add that as an answer.  No quotes needed.

Comment: BOOOOOOOMM thank you Broken, that worked. Love you.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the variable `$indtag` where you should be using the column name `indtag`:

```
SELECT `id`, `$indtag` FROM `beyonce` WHERE `$indtag` LIKE '%$indtag%'
              ^                              ^
```

And as @tadman points outs, don't do it this way, use `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` with a prepared statement or you are in for a wild ride.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the column being selected is not `indtag` but is actually dynamically changing. Based on the question, the value of `$indtag` could be 'ang', 'rom', 'dece', ... etc.

Comment: I'm specifically referring to this line:
_The table has fields for `id`s, `quote`s, then **an individual column for each tag** (`ang` for anger being an example)._

Comment: BrokenBinary is correct in this, it is a dynamically changing column.

Comment: So this is a valid example: `SELECT id, rom FROM beyonce WHERE rom LIKE '%rom%'`   ???

Comment: Yes, abra. exactly. There are 27 columns, one for each tag. Within those it has the tag (rom--some double tags like rom+fam(ily), rom+fri(ends), etc.). I'm trying to grab the ID and the similar tags.

Comment: OK, that is a horrendous design, but look at @BrokenBinary's comment on the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This line in your code doesn't need quotes.

```
echo $row['$indtag'];  // Won't work
echo $row[$indtag];    // Will work
```